# iPad Application becomes slow after a while

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a point of sale iPad application which works perfectly for the first few transactions. After about 10 transactions back to back, the app becomes painfully slow. The UI takes more than a second to respond to touch down events. So when I kill the application and restart it, it works perfectly again. I used the following function to check for free VM
The response time seems to be increasing exponentially with each new transaction and eventually the app becomes unusable.

```
-(void)print_free_memory
{
        mach_port_t host_port;
        mach_msg_type_number_t host_size;
        vm_size_t pagesize;

    host_port = mach_host_self();
    host_size = sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t) / sizeof(integer_t);
    host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);

    vm_statistics_data_t vm_stat;

    if (host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vm_stat, &host_size) !=    KERN_SUCCESS)
         NSLog(@"Failed to fetch vm statistics");

/* Stats in bytes */
    natural_t mem_used = (vm_stat.active_count +
                      vm_stat.inactive_count +
                      vm_stat.wire_count) * pagesize;
    natural_t mem_free = vm_stat.free_count * pagesize;
    natural_t mem_total = mem_used + mem_free;
  //      [self displayAlert:@"Memory" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"used: %u   free: %u total: %u", mem_used, mem_free, mem_total]];
    // NSLog(@"used: %u free: %u total: %u", mem_used, mem_free, mem_total);
```

}

The memory usage seems more or less constant. So,I'm not sure about what the problem is. Could anyone please help me out with this issue? I've tried setting objects to nil by myself. But that doesn't seem to be improving the issue.

Comment: Almost sounds like the UI elements are being created, kept, and new ones created each time you do a transaction. Just a thought.

Comment: Have you done any time profiling?

Comment: Use Instruments to profile your app.

Comment: thanks for your response Almo. I am adding subviews each time. But I do set the IBOutlets and UIViews to nil after each transaction. Do you know of any tools in instruments which would tell me if the views are actually getting released. I am sorry if my questions seem trivial :)

Comment: @MikeWeller: yes I have used the memory allocations and leaks tool. The live bytes seems more or less constant.

Comment: @Wain: I haven't done time profiling yet. Will definitely check it out.

Comment: When you set the UIViews to nil, do you also remove them from their superview?

Comment: @CleverError: yes I do

Comment: Like Mike said, use Instruments. Sounds like you should use the CPU tool as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses. I was able to figure out the reason for the slow down, thanks to you guys.Below were the results from the Time Profiling.

There was this method

Running Time    Self        Symbol Name

250185.0ms   81.3%  90.0        -[tcCreditCardViewController blinkT]

I had set this to be triggered by NSTimer and did not invalidate the timer after the new subview was added. Once I did that, the application is running as smoothly as ever.